# Spring cron job runs every minute

Tags: spring, cron

I am using below cron expression to run Spring Cron job every minute.. But somehow it is not running. Please suggest.

0 0/1 * * * ?

I have also tried 0 0/1 1 * * ? still it doesnt run. I am first time using cron job so please help me.

Comment: Try this: 0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *